# I can't plot Cassini oval in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Recently I need to plot the [Cassini oval](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CassiniOvals.html)

but it works just for b/a>=1.
here is my simple code. for clarifying I employed many temporary variables.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import cos, sin, sqrt, radians

# setting the values of a , b
a =2    
B= np.arange(1.9,2.1, 0.05)

# containing the radian values
rads = np.arange(0, (2 * np.pi), 0.03)

x=[]
y=[]
# plotting the ellipse
for b in B:    
    sin2=np.sin(2*rads)
    sin22=np.power(sin2,2)
    ba4=(b/a)**4
    tmp1=ba4-sin22
    tmp2=np.sqrt(tmp1)
    tmp3=(np.cos(2*rads))+tmp2
    r=np.sqrt((tmp3))* (a)

    x=np.multiply(r, np.cos(rads))
    y= np.multiply(r, np.sin(rads))

    plt.plot(x,y,'g')
plt.show()
```

and the result is

[image]

Comment: Did you try a larger range for the angles? E.g `rads = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 500)`?

Comment: Yes, I tested that but it didn't matter.

Comment: Did you notice `tmp1` or `tmp3` can be negative in some circumstances? Numpy gets confused when you try extracting the square root of negative numbers.

Comment: yes, I read some blogs and tried many ways, but I think my mistake is in the mathematical formulation understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link you provided, it looks like the range over which you are plotting the Cassini ovals change depending on how the ratio `b/a` compares to 1. For instance, when `a<b`, the range is [image] whereas it is restricted to  [image] when `a>=b`.
Similarly, when `a>=b`, the curve becomes two disjoint ovals while it is a single one when `a<b`. Consequently, in order to plot the disjoints ovals you need to plot all different solutions for `r` (changing signs etc.)

See code below where I plotted the Casini curves when `a=2` and the `b/a` ratio goes from 0.1 to 1.5 (same ratio modulation than the figure in the link you provided)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import radians

a=2    
B= np.arange(0.2,3, 0.3)#b/a ration goes form 0.1 to 1.5
x=[]
y=[]
step=0.00001
lw=1.
colors = plt.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0,1,len(B)))[::-1]

#Function  to compute the first part of the Cassini ovals
def cas_process(rads):
  sin2=np.sin(2*rads)
  sin22=np.power(sin2,2)
  ba4=(b/a)**4
  diff=ba4-sin22
  sq=np.sqrt(diff)
  return sq

for b,i in zip(B,range(len(B))):    
  if a>=b:
    theta_0=0.5*np.arcsin((b/a)**2) 
    rads = np.arange(-theta_0, theta_0, step)[1:-1] #defining appropriate range for the b/a ratio
    tmp2=cas_process(rads)

    #Getting all solutions
    tmp3p=(np.cos(2*rads))+tmp2
    tmp3m=(np.cos(2*rads))-tmp2
    rpp=np.sqrt(tmp3p)*a
    rmm=np.sqrt(tmp3m)*(-a)
    rpm=np.sqrt(tmp3p)*(-a)
    rmp=np.sqrt(tmp3m)*(a)

    xpp=np.multiply(rpp, np.cos(rads))
    ypp= np.multiply(rpp, np.sin(rads))
    xpm=np.multiply(rpm, np.cos(rads))
    ypm= np.multiply(rpm, np.sin(rads))
    xmp=np.multiply(rmp, np.cos(rads))
    ymp= np.multiply(rmp, np.sin(rads))
    xmm=np.multiply(rmm, np.cos(rads))
    ymm= np.multiply(rmm, np.sin(rads))
    
    #Plotting disjoints ovals. Each of the curves below are necessary to get the complete picture
    plt.plot(xpp,ypp,color=colors[i],lw=lw,label='b/a='+str(np.round(b/a,2)))
    plt.plot(xmm,ymm,color=colors[i],lw=lw)
    plt.plot(xpm,ypm,color=colors[i],lw=lw)
    plt.plot(xmp,ymp,color=colors[i],lw=lw)

  elif a<b:
    rads = np.arange(0, (2 * np.pi), step) #defining appropriate range for the b/a ratio
    tmp2=cas_process(rads)
    tmp3=(np.cos(2*rads))+tmp2
    r=np.sqrt((tmp3))* (a)
    x=np.multiply(r, np.cos(rads))
    y= np.multiply(r, np.sin(rads))

    plt.plot(x,y,color=colors[i],lw=lw,label='b/a='+str(np.round(b/a,2)))
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.0))
plt.show()
```

and the output gives:

[image]

And below is the result you get for the range `B= np.arange(1.9,2.1, 0.05)` you specified in your question:

[image]

Comment: thank you. it works. "All things are difficult before they are easy".

Comment: Happy to hear! If you found my answer helpful, you can mark your question as answered by clicking on the green checkmark next to my answer. Thx!